# Tires always spins 49cc motor

Tags: clutch, scooter, stall

Just bought this scooter and in order for it to start the back tire has to be off the ground and it keeps spinning and once the tire hits the ground it shuts off [image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I would have expected that to have a centrifugal clutch - one that engages as the engine revs increase.

If this is now direct drive, has it been "adjusted" to be direct drive as the centrifugal mechanism has failed?